# JWT configuration in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm developing a Django application for Windows with Pyhton 2.7.15. I need to implement an authentication mechanism where if a user has a specific JWT token, he can browse the application (in other words, I just need to verify the token and not generate it). The token is very easy and maybe will be something like this:

**Header**

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

**Payload**

```
{
  "iss": "customIssuer"
}
```

**Signature**

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  secret
)
```

To implement the verification's service, I installed the [Rest framework JWT](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) tools and I modifyed my `setting.py` in this way:

```
...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ISSUER': 'customIssuer'
}

...
```

then I modifyed the `urls.py`:

```
...

from rest_framework_jwt.views import verify_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api-token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
    ...
]
```

Finally, using Postman, I tryed to send a POST request with the above token but I get a `400 Bad Error` error with this body:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid payload."
    ]
}
```

Investigating about the reason I realize that I must add the username claim in the payload but I don't want to. It's possible to configure the application to ignore that claim?

Comment: `api-token-verify`, checking token which sent in payload like `"token": "<token_key>"`. So before using this endpoint, you must be login in system with correct user and get valid token key.

Comment: In truth the base idea is to use two different application. Only the first one has a login function while the latter (my Django application) accepts only users with valid token (regardless the username). For this reason I'm using only this endpoint.